# windows batch execute about call command

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

when i write with batch command using `call`,the command is:

```
call d:\Hot_gen.bat %B_SCRIPT_TARGET% %B_BACKUP_TARGET%>>%logdir%\hot_gen%date:~0,4%%date:~5,2%%date:~8,2%.log
```

But in the execute the result is:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\BAT>call d:\Hot_gen.bat d:\ora\scripttar d:\oraba
k\baktar  \hot_gen20131002.log 1>>d:\ora\log
refuse access
```

Why has the result? I just want to `>>` the call result to log file.

Thank you!

Comment: Did these solutions help you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this to avoid trailing spaces in `%logdir%`:

```
set "logdir=d:\ora\log"
>>"%logdir%\hot_gen%date:~0,4%%date:~5,2%%date:~8,2%.log" call d:\Hot_gen.bat %B_SCRIPT_TARGET% %B_BACKUP_TARGET%
```

Answer (score 1):

The value of the environment variable `logdir` has a space at the end.

This is most likely because you've got a line somewhere that says

```
 set logdir=d:\ora\log
```

and there's an extra space at the end of the line.